# Failure when using setattr to add field to Django form class

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to write use Django `FormView` and a bit of ingenuity to create a view which will allow me to get inputs from a user that will be fed to a function.  I'd like the code to be reusable, so I'd like to make a view that will be able to take a target function as a parameter and automagically create a form appropriate to that function.  There is more plumbing to be done, but the general idea would be:

```
class FormViewForFunction(FormView):
    template_name = '...'
    func = None

    def get_form_class(self):
        class _FunctionForm(forms.Form):
            pass

        a = inspect.getargspec(self.func)
        for argname in a['args']:
            setattr(_FunctionForm, argname, forms.CharField())
        return _FunctionForm
```

The idea would be that then you could set up something in your URLConf that used `FormViewForFunction.as_view(func=***insert any function you want***)` and you would wind up being presented with a form that was appropriate for specifying parameters for that function.  Let's not worry about what would happen on form submission.  For now I'm just stuck getting the form to generate properly.

With the code above, the form doesn't wind up having any fields!  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class FormViewForFunction(FormView):
   template_name = '...'
   func = None

   def get_form_class(self):
       a = inspect.getargspec(self.func)
       class _FunctionForm(forms.Form):
           def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
               super(_FunctionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
               for argname in a['args']:
                   self.fields[argname] = forms.CharField()
       return _FunctionForm
```

Answer (score 3):

form's fields are initialized during initialization, you should override the __init__ method and then append the fields to the `self.fields` dictionary

Comment: Is there no way to do it in the spirit of what's above?

Comment: @8one6 you simply need to loop over a['args'] within _FunctionForm's __init__ method.

Comment: At the time that a particular form is initialized, or at the time that the class is defined?  Again, my goal here is to have a function that returns a class that is appropriate to a particular context.  So at the time the class is created (via the function) there is no particular instance at hand (and so the init method is not being called).